# Unable to get a palindrome check to work

Tags: c, function

I'm writing a code to check if the inputted string is a palindrome or not, in C. So far I have written functions that reverses the input string and compares the original to the reversed string. Regardless of what the input was, the output is always "Is not a palindrome". Is there an error somewhere in the code? Or do I have to try different method? The code is listed below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *string);
int testStrings(char *a, char *b);

int main()
{
    char string[100];
    char string2[100];

    printf("Please Enter a string:\n");
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);
    strcpy(string2, string);
    reverse(string);

    printf("Here's what you typed:%s\n",string2);
    printf("Here's the Reversed:%s\n",string);
    testStrings(string, string2);

    return 0;
}

void reverse(char *s)
{
    int c, i , j;
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s) - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }
    return;
}

int testStrings(char *a, char *b)
{
    int i;
    int length;
    int c;

    length = strlen(b) - 1;

    for (i = 0; 1 <= length; i++) {
        if (b[i] != a[i]) {
            c = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (c = 1) {
        printf("The input is not a palindrome.\n");
    } else {
        printf("The inpiy is a palindrome.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgets` includes the trailing `newline`.

Comment: Why are you reversing the string? Work it from both ends until they do not match or you cross the middle

Comment: @EdHeal: Is that not what the `reverse` function does already?

Comment: Unrelated but this is completely wrong: `if (c = 1) {`

Comment: It is using a copy. Just use the one string.

Comment: `if (c=1)`? `1<=length`??

Comment: In your `testStrings` function, you want to initialize `c` to `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `fgets` includes also the new line character in the string that corresponds to pressed Enter key. You should remove it if it is present in the string. For example

```
size_t n = strlen( string );

if ( n && string[n-1] == '\n' ) string[--n] = '\0';
```

Take into account that it is better to exclude print statements from function
`testStrings` and place them in main. The function should return either 1 or 0 depending on whether strings are equal each other. And there is no need to call `strlen` within the function.

The function could ne written much simpler and look the following way

```
int testStrings( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    while ( *s1 && *s1 == *s2 ) ++s1, ++s2;

    return *s1 == *s2;
}
```

As for function reverse then it is better to write it such a way that it would copy the source string in the reverse order in the destination string. For example

```
char * reverse_copy( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char *p = s1;
    const char *q = s2 + strlen( s2 );

    while ( q != s2 ) *p++ = *--q;

    *p = '\0';

    return s1;
}
```

The function calls woul look like

```
printf( "Here's what you typed:%s\n", string );
printf( "Here's the Reversed:%s\n", reverse_copy( string2, string ) );

int isPalindrome = testStrings( string, string2 );

// print stetements depending on whether the result is equal to 1 or 0
```

Now if to combine all together you can get the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int testStrings( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    while ( *s1 && *s1 == *s2 ) ++s1, ++s2;

    return *s1 == *s2;
}

char * reverse_copy( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char *p = s1;
    const char *q = s2 + strlen( s2 );

    while ( q != s2 ) *p++ = *--q;

    *p = '\0';

    return s1;
}

#define N   100

int main( void ) 
{
    char string[N];
    char string2[N];

    printf( "Please Enter a string: " );
    fgets( string, N, stdin );

    size_t n = strlen( string );

    if ( n && string[n-1] == '\n' ) string[--n] = '\0';

    printf( "\nHere's what you typed: %s\n", string );
    printf( "Here's the Reversed: %s\n", reverse_copy( string2, string ) );

    if ( testStrings( string, string2 ) )
    {
        printf( "\nThe input is a palindrome.\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "\nThe input is not a palindrome.\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And if to enter for example

```
123454321
```

then the output will be

```
Please Enter a string: 123454321

Here's what you typed: 123454321
Here's the Reversed: 123454321

The input is a palindrome.
```

Take into account that you could determine whether a string is a palindrome without using the second character array. In this case the function could look the following way

```
int isPalindrome( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n / 2 && s[i] == s[n-1-i] ) ++i;

    return i == n / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work with `fgets` because it keeps the trailing `\n` with the string; `gets` does not do that.

From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/):

> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str.

To fix this, adjust the length to account for the trailing `\n` mark: go to the end of the string, and move back until you see a non-`\n` character.

I try to edit your code and it works. Errata `if (c=1)` and `1<=length` I've fixed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *string);
int testStrings(char *a, char *b);

int main()
{
    char string[100];
    char string2[100];

    printf("Please Enter a string:\n");
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);


    size_t n = strlen( string );

    if ( n && string[n-1] == '\n' ) string[--n] = '\0';


    strcpy(string2, string);
    reverse(string);

    printf("Here's what you typed:%s\n",string2);
    printf("Here's the Reversed:%s\n",string);
    testStrings(string, string2);

    return 0;
}

void reverse(char *s)
{
    int c, i , j;
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s) - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }
    return;
}

int testStrings(char *a, char *b)
{
    int i;
    int length;
    int c;

    length = strlen(b) - 1;

    for (i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
        if (b[i] != a[i]) {
            c = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (c == 1) {
        printf("The input is not a palindrome.\n");
    } else {
        printf("The inpiy is a palindrome.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully at your program output, you'll see there is an extra `newline`. I entered `abcdef` and it reported

```
Here's what you typed:abcdef
          <--- extra blank line here>
Here's the Reversed:
fedcba
The input is not a palindrome.
```

the extra `newline` is not generated by your code, which prints a single newlines

```
printf("Here's what you typed:%s\n",string2);
printf("Here's the Reversed:%s\n",string);
```

This is because `fgets` holds the terminating `newline` as part of the string.

My favourite way to remove the trailing `newline` included by `fgets` is

```
string [ strcspn(string, "\r\n") ] = 0;
```

since it will handle different OS conventions for text file end-of-line without grumble.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can do is replace `fgets(string, 100, stdin)` by `gets(string)` because of the trailing `\n` character included by `fgets()`

more over, in `testStrings()` you should

- `int c=0` Initialize c.
- `for (i = 0; i <= length; i++) {` Change 1 to i
- `if (c == 1) {` change `=` to `==`

Here's the complete working code with above changes:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 void reverse(char *string);
 int testStrings(char *a, char *b);
 int main()
 {
   char string[100];
   char string2[100];

   printf("Please Enter a string:\n");
   gets(string);
   strcpy(string2, string);
   reverse(string);

   printf("Here's what you typed:%s\n",string2);
   printf("Here's the Reversed:%s\n",string);
   testStrings(string, string2);
   return;
 }

void reverse(char *s)
{
    int c, i , j;
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }
   return;
}

int testStrings(char *a, char *b)
{
   int i;
   int length;
   int c=0;

   length=strlen(b)-1;
   for(i=0;i <=length; i++)
   {
         if(b[i]!=a[i])
        {
        c = 1;
        break;
        }
   }
   if(c==1)
   {
      printf("The input is not a palindrome.\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("The inpiy is a palindrome.\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Also to mention that you could have used much better algorithms to check palindrome.

Comment: Whats a much better way of doing this?

Comment: Simply start checking the string from both ends and move on till you cross the middle or find a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

That's an awful lot of code.  Do you have to reverse the string?  Is that a requirement?  An optional solution.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Need an argument\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int len = strlen(argv[1]) - 1;
    int i = 0;
    int palindrome = 1;
    for ( ; i < len; ++i, --len) {
        if (argv[1][i] != argv[1][len]) {
            palindrome = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (palindrome) {
        printf("I am a Palindrome\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("I am NOT a Palindrome\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but here is a much cleaner solution:

```
int recursiveTest(char* str,int len)
{
    if (len <= 1)
        return 1;
    if (str[0] != str[len-1])
        return 0;
    return recursiveTest(str+1,len-2);
}

int isPalindrome(char* str)
{
    return recursiveTest(str,strlen(str));
}

int main()
{
    char str[100];

    printf("Please Enter a string:\n");
    scanf("%99s",str);

    if (isPalindrome(str))
        printf("The input is a palindrome.\n");
    else
        printf("The input is not a palindrome.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is recursion a bit expensive when a simple loop would be better?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[100];

    printf("Please Enter a string:\n");
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);

    size_t len = strlen(string) - 1;
    if (string[len] == '\n') len --;

    for (size_t left = 0; left < len && string[left] == string[len]; ++left, --len) { }

    printf("%s is %s palidrome\n", string, (left < len ? " not a ", ""));
    return 0;
}
```

Is the smallest I can get the code with it being reasonable readable.